# AdMob/Firebase integration with SwiftUI using cocoapods: Found an unexpected Mach-O header code: 0x72613c21

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, swiftui, admob

I'm following the instructions [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admob/ios/quick-start) to integrate AdMob into my iOS app but whenever I try to run the app, I always get the same error:

```
Details

Found an unexpected Mach-O header code: 0x72613c21
Domain: DVTMachOErrorDomain
Code: 0
User Info: {
    NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion = "";
}
--


System Information

macOS Version 11.3.1 (Build 20E241)
Xcode 12.5 (18205) (Build 12E262)
Timestamp: 2021-05-18T01:43:17+02:00
```

I have been searching around the whole internet for hours and I haven't found anything that helps.

These are the libraries I have:

[image: Link binaries with libraries]

Does anybody have the same problem?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: I have tried to remove Cocoapods and install the frameworks manually, and I get this error now:

[image: error]

This is what I have in the frameworks folder after adding the frameworks (I don't know if perhaps I've added them in the wrong way):

[image: frameworks]

Comment: Can you try the solution provided here? https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/6472

Answer (score 0):

Try removing CouchbaseLite.framework and CouchbaseLiteListener.framework from the Embedded Binaries section on target

Comment: Please see my update above (there's no such frameworks)